# How do i convert List to String

Tags: java, list

I am getting the value for the first three columns, but not the value for the last column. How do I convert a List to a String so I can get the value for the Organization column?

This is my code:

```
String appname = "abc";
String path = "//home/exportfile//";
String filename = path+"ApplicationExport-"+appname+".txt";
String ret = "false";

        QueryOptions ops = new QueryOptions();
    Filter [] filters = new Filter[1];
    filters[0] = Filter.eq("application.name", appname);
    ops.add(filters);

    List props = new ArrayList();
    props.add("identity.name");

    //Do search
    Iterator it = context.search(Link.class, ops, props);

    //Build file and export header row
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
    out.write("IdentityName,UserName,WorkforceID,Organization");
    out.newLine();          

    //Iterate Search Results
    if (it!=null)
    {                               
            while ( it.hasNext() ) {

                    //Get link and create object
                    Object [] record = it.next();
                    String identityName = (String) record[0];
                    Identity user = (Identity) context.getObject(Identity.class, identityName);

                    //Get Identity attributes for export
                    String workforceid = (String) user.getAttribute("workforceID");                 

                    //Get application attributes for export
                    String userid="";

                    List links = user.getLinks();
                    if (links!=null)
                    {
                            Iterator lit = links.iterator();
                            while (lit.hasNext())
                            {
                                    Link l = lit.next();
                                    String lname = l.getApplicationName();
                                    if (lname.equalsIgnoreCase(appname))
                                    {
                                              userid = (String) l.getAttribute("User Name");
                                              List organizations = l.getAttribute("Organization");

                                              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                              String listItemsSeparator = ","; // this you can change to anything you want, it separates items from list

                                                                                                            for (Object organization : organizations)
                                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                                            sb.append(organization.toString());
                                                                                                                            sb.append(listItemsSeparator);
                                                                                                                    }

                                                                                                                    org = sb.toString().trim();

                                    }
                            }
                    }                   

                    //Output file
                    out.write(identityName+","+userid+","+workforceid+","+org);                             
                    out.newLine();                                                                          
                    out.flush();
            }

                     ret="true";
    }

    //Close file and return
    out.close();
    return ret;
```

This code writes Void for the value of the Organization column. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Your code is really messy, but I think that I know what you are asking for:

```
    List links = user.getLinks();
    if (links != null) {
        Iterator lit = links.iterator();
        while (lit.hasNext()) {
            Link l = lit.next();
            String lname = l.getApplicationName();
            if (lname.equalsIgnoreCase(appname)) {
                userid = (String) l.getAttribute("User Name");
                List organizations = l.getAttribute("Organization");

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String listItemsSeparator = " "; // this you can change to anything you want, it separates items from list

                //iterating over list, to convert it to single String 
                for (Object organization : organizations) {
                    sb.append(organization.toString());
                    sb.append(listItemsSeparator);
                }

                orgList = sb.toString().trim();

            }
        }
    }
```

edit2:

```
while (it.hasNext()) {

    //Get link and create object
    Object [] record = it.next();
    String identityName = (String) record[0];
    Identity user = (Identity) context.getObject(Identity.class, identityName);

    //Get Identity attributes for export
    String workforceid = (String) user.getAttribute("workforceID");

    //Get application attributes for export
    String userid="";

    List links = user.getLinks();
    if (links!=null)
    {
        Iterator lit = links.iterator();
        while (lit.hasNext())
        {
            Link l = lit.next();
            String lname = l.getApplicationName();
            if (lname.equalsIgnoreCase(appname))
            {
                userid = (String) l.getAttribute("User Name");
                List orgList = l.getAttribute("Organization");
                if(organization &lt; orgList.size()) {
                    String singleOrganization = orgList.get(organization);
                    organization++;


                    //Output file
                    out.write(identityName+","+userid+","+workforceid+","+orgList);
                    out.newLine();
                    out.flush();

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: currently i am getting the output in this fashion below..

IdentityName,UserName,WorkforceID,Organization

bthomas,bthomas001,id123456,Finance, HR

can i get it below way.
IdentityName,UserName,WorkforceID,Organization

bthomas,bthomas001,id123456,Finance

bthomas,bthomas001,id123456,HR

and for that what should i need to do ?

Comment: I am getting below error"
 illegal use of undefined variable, class, or 'void' literal : at Line: 68 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.FileWriter; import java.io.File; import java.io.B . . . '' : )

Comment: @user1565893 First of all - the code that you provided is impossible to be compiled. Secondly, it's my fault that I didn't have time / will to tell you what you are doing wrong and how to fix it... Anyway if you resolve compilation errors on your side, and compare mine code to yours you should get the idea how to do it. Problem is that you have very complex code and you lack basic knowledge - how to iterate a list of variables. Learning it on such example, as provided above, isn't good idea.

Comment: you are correct. my java skills are not good.
and compare your code and mine code.and changed it.but still getting that error.

Comment: @user1565893 to fix you problem you should use my first code, but don't append all organizations to newly created list of them. In place of that iterate over them, and every time print one of them with the whole string that should come before - `"identityName+","+userid+","+workforceid+"` + `oneOrganization` (again - do that that last loop that iterates over organizations)

Comment: I tried but i am still stuck with getting all the values in one row.

I have updated my code above,

Answer (score 1):

You really have not provided too much information about what is going on in your app, or why you are getting a list for the organization. But try this:

```
out.write(identityName+","+userid+","+workforceid+","+(String)orgList.get(0));
```

Also your list is not parameterized, So we have no idea what type of objects that list is storing.

Comment: in my app...organiation attribbute is a multivalued..i.e.: each identiy can have multiple organization associated with him...the reason organization is not getting exported

Comment: got this error;
Attempt to resolve method: get() on undefined variable or class name: orgList : at Line: 97 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.FileWriter; import java.io.File; import java.io.B . . . '' : orgList .get ( 0 )

Comment: You are declaring orgList inside of the loop, try declaring it at the top of your file with your other variables and then assigning it inside the loop. Then, when you do  out.write the variable will be in scope.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the default toString methods of the objects in the list. Calling toString on a list will cause the toString method of all objects in it to be called. You could also loop over the list and print each value.